# ArrayList<T> with different types for T

Tags: java, templates, generics, arraylist

I want to have a list that have different but similar types.
For example, I want to put a list of different validator classes in one list.

Eg:

```
ArrayList<T> validators = new ArrayList<T>();
validators.add(new StringValidator());
validators.add(new IntegerValidator());
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a complete example of how you can do it:

First, define an interface:

```
public interface Validator {
    void validate();
}
```

Then, create an implementation:

```
public class IntegerValidator implements Validator {

    public void validate() {
        // Validate
    }
}
```

The String validator implementation:

```
public class StringValidator implements Validator {
    public void validate() {
        // Validate
    }
}
```

Here is the client code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Validator> v = new ArrayList<Validator>();
        v.add(new StringValidator());
        v.add(new IntegerValidator());

        for (Validator validator : v) {
            validator.validate();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to add, then

```
ArrayList<Validator> validators = new ArrayList<Validator>();
validators.add(new StringValidator());
validators.add(new IntegerValidator());
```

is perfectly fine. But if you want your subclass type to be referred by superclass type, then

Use `ArrayList< ? extends Validator> validators = new ArrayList<Validator>(); where all your validators extends`Validator` if you want to refer to subclasses of Validator using the superclass reference. Read about [generics wildcard operator here](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/28/generics-the-wildcard-operator/)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if the validators share a superclass you can supply that as the type.

```
List<Validator> validators = new ArrayList<Validator>();
validators.add(new StringValidator());
validators.add(new IntegerValidator());
```

Many of the answers here specify the first type as `<? extends Validator>` but that's unnecessary. It would allow you to specify the second type as a Validator subclass, i.e.

```
List<? extends Validator> validators = new ArrayList<ValidatorSubClass>();
```

Answer (score 2):

create a super class named Validator,and let StringValidator and IntegerValidator extends(or implement)Validator, then you can init your ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<Validator> validators = new ArrayList<Validator>();
validators.add(new StringValidator());
validators.add(new IntegerValidator());
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can always do:

```
ArrayList<object> validators = new ArrayList<object>();
validators.add(new StringValidator());
validators.add(new IntegerValidator());
```

and in your case also

```
ArrayList<Validator> validators = new ArrayList<Validator>();
validators.add(new StringValidator());
validators.add(new IntegerValidator());
```

you see, when you state what's `T` then only the class you declared or extended classes can be put in the `ArrayList`. so when you state a common parent such as `Validator` then you can add botch `StringValidator` and `IntegerValidator` to the `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html), you can use

```
List<? extends Validator> validators = new ArrayList<>();
validators.add(new StringValidator());
validators.add(new IntegerValidator());
```

where `StringValidator` and `IntegerValidator` extend `Validator`.